# IIS removed application still remain appearing as folder content view (able to convert to application back again)

Tags: iis, web-server, web-applications

*IIS 7.5
*Windows Server 2008 R2
I have a folder physical path which is directed from two applications in IIS.
'Pineapple' and 'PineappleJR'. 'PineappleJR' was deleted, but it remains appearing in the node tree as content view folder which I can't deleted because is linking all the directory from 'Pineapple'. Also there is no option in cotenxt menu nor Actions Pane.
How do I remove 'PineappleJR' from node tree list and keep 'Pineapple' application ?
Thank you for your attention

Comment: can you recreate the PineappleJr folder in the physical file system, then remove the mapping in IIS before physically deleting the folder?

Comment: @Sage I not too familiar with web servers. You're saying doing a backup of 'PineappleJR' physical files? could you explain the 'remove the mapping in IIS'?

Comment: perhaps you can upload one or more screenshots of the problem so your issue will be more clear?